# The Other as a changed form of the Beast

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, product-identification, vampire-the-requiem

I remember in one of the splat books that there was a passage to change the beast to something they call "the Other" and have a hard time finding it again.

I recently reread the Sonja Blue novels and wanted to give it a try and remembered there being said passage but cant find it anymore.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concept of "the Other" as a replacement for the Beast appears in the *Vampire: The Requiem Chronicler's Guide*, published in 2006. Details for this variant appear on pages 59-65, but it's summed up in the introduction like this:

> **The Other** wonders how Kindred would find eternity if the Beast weren't a ferocious, ravenous devourer but, instead, an insidious and devious schemer.

In brief, the Other presents as a second personality, a voice in the character's mind, always criticising the vampire's humane actions and trying to persuade them to kill and feed. It works through dialogue, not emotions or instinct like the Beast does, and allows for more finesse and precision in presenting the temptations of the vampiric condition. The Other's priorities are satiation and personal safety, and it tempts characters with promises of secrets about vampire history and abilities.

The rules differences include removing the Predator's Taint, replacing Frenzy with Imprisonment (the Other takes control of the vampire's body, with various advantages to the Other), and changing the terms and effects of Riding the Wave (which becomes "Allying with the Other") and reaching zero Humanity (effectively permanent Imprisonment).

Comment: Thank you very much. I even looked through that specific book but seem to have passed it or something.

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know if the composure and resolve upgraded to 6 is meant for the other or truly also for the character would you?

Comment: @Bazhell that’s a separate question, but it seems pretty clear from the text that it applies to a vampire only while they are Imprisoned, so effectively only the Other gets that benefit. (It is explicitly stated to apply to snowmen, ie the Other equivalent of draugr.)